# MATLAB image processing missing areas

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pixel, gaussian, noise-reduction

I have 3 versions of an image, one = it has 5 areas missing (large white pixelated area), two = it has lots of noise and distortion, three = the ground truth image, the original.

I have started to remove the noise and distortian from image two to make it as similar to the ground truth image.

The next step is to find the areas of image one which are missing, and then once image two is nearly exactly similar to the ground truth image, use it to fill in the missing areas of image one.

I am new to matlab and have no idea where to start with finding the missing areas and then later filling them with the denoised areas from image two. 
Any help or guidance I'd be extremely grateful

Answer (score 0):

You can use image `inpainting` methods to fill gaps in your second image, denoise and enhance your first image by solving a `deconvolution` problem found in literature depending on your noise and distiortion types and find your empty areas in third image by `find(I3==255)` in MATLAB and use thhe same indices to get pixel values from thwo other images.

Comment: Cool, thank you for the help I will look into those functions now and try and apply them :)